# Unit Test Mock Rejected Promise in Angular2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angularfire2

In am trying to test an Angular2 Authentication Service (`authService`), in particular mocking the `AngularFireAuth` provider so I can control and test the various authentication scenarios by spying on, and returning values of the `AngularFireAuth` methods e.g. `signInAnonymously`.

Below is a excerpt from my test spec. You can see the initial `authState` is an Observable of null — we're not authenticated. `authService` should then try and authenticate anonymously (with `signInAnonymously`).

In `AngularFire` the `signInAnonymously` method returns a promise. I want this to be rejected and the error caught.

This is just once scenario but if I can figure this out I can probably work out the rest.

### auth.service.spec.ts

```
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { MockUser } from './testing/mock-user';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

let authState: MockUser;
let mockAngularFireAuth: any = {
  auth: jasmine.createSpyObj('auth', [
    'signInAnonymously',
    'signInWithPopup',
    'signOut'
  ]),
  authState: Observable.of(null)
};
let service: AuthService;

fdescribe('AuthService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: mockAngularFireAuth },
        { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([ AuthService ], (authService: AuthService) => {
    service = authService;
  }));

  // TODO: Test `authState`  is `null` and throw
  describe('when we can’t authenticate', () => {
    it('should thow', () => {
      mockAngularFireAuth.auth.signInAnonymously.and.returnValue(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reject('fooBar');
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authState: firebase.User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { this.init(); }

  private init(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((authState) => {
      console.log(1, authState);

      if (authState === null) {
        console.log(2, authState);

        this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
          .then((authState) => {
            console.log(3, authState);

            this.authState = authState;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(4, error.message);

            throw new Error(error.message);
          });
      } else {
        console.log(5, authState);

        this.authState = authState;
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(6, error.message);

      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` at line 21:11 in `auth.service.ts`; this is as you would expect, the `.then((authState) => {...` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AuthService` is instantiated before mocking `signInAnonymously`.

Instead, it can be

```
  describe('when we can’t authenticate', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockAngularFireAuth.auth.signInAnonymously.and.returnValue(Promise.reject('fooBar'));
    });

    it('...', inject([ AuthService ], (authService: AuthService) => {
      ...
```

Comment: Ah, I thought as I created the spy object then it could be hijacked later on. I'll try this shortly, thank you